# AngularJS, string not interpolating $routeParams values

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a link using routeParams of the route angularJs class. which works pretty well but for some reason it doesn't interpolate my strings.

I have tried the following:

1. {{username}}   as in the controller i set $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
2. {{ Repo.username }} as the controller is called RepoController.

however both had no result except printing it as a string literal on the screen.my code is as below

App.js

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"])

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/main", {
          templateUrl: "main.html",
          controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/user/:username", {
          templateUrl: "user.html",
          controller: "UserController"
        })
        .when("/repo/:username/:reponame", {
          templateUrl: "repo.html",
          controller: "RepoController"
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: "/main"
        })
    });

}());
```

RepoController.js

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer")

  var RepoController = function($scope, github, $routeParams) {

  $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
  $scope.reponame = $routeParams.reponame;


  app.controller("RepoController", ["$scope", "github", "$routeParams", RepoController]);

}());
```

Repo.html

```
<section>

  {{ username }}
  <br />
  {{ repo.name }}

</section>
```

There is a plunker available:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oGJJOUfCqW8G7OAXxXGa?p=preview

thanks a lot for any help. Cheers!

Comment: You have syntax error , controller function not closing `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of syntactic and semantic issues in the Plunkr that may be affecting your actual code.

1. You have a syntax error in the RepoController.js -- you do not close the `RepoController` function declaration with `}`
2. You are not including `<script src=RepoController.js>` in `index.html`
3. `$scope.repo` is not an object with a name property. In your template, use `reponame` instead or you could do `$scope.repo = {name: $routeParams.reponame}`

Comment: thanks for the swift response. it worked after fixing these 3 points. first 2 were a bit sloppy of me though. anyways cheers!